# Serialize MappingJacksonValue

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, redis

**Goal**

Cache MappingJacksonValue while returning from the spring boot controller.

**Steps to reproduce**

***Method-***

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@Cacheable(key = "#id")
fun getAccessRoleDetails(
    @PathVariable("id")
    @NotBlank(message = "Please provide a access role id")
    id: UUID
): MappingJacksonValue {
    println(
        """
        called in port ${serverProperties.port}
    """.trimIndent()
    )
    val accessRole = accessRoleRepo.findById(id.toString())
    if (accessRole.isEmpty) {
        throw GenericException(
            errorMessage = "not found",
            code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()
        )
    }
    val mappingJacksonValue = MappingJacksonValue(accessRole)
    mappingJacksonValue.filters = SimpleFilterProvider()
        .addFilter(
            "filterOne",
            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(
                "id",
                "code",
                "createdDate",
                "description",
                "lastUpdated",
                "title",
                "accessControlPolicies"
            )
        )
        .addFilter(
            "filterTwo",
            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(
                "id",
                "code",
                "createdDate",
                "description",
                "lastUpdated",
            )
        )
    return mappingJacksonValue
}
```

***Error-***

```
2021-10-14 11:40:01.525 ERROR 7308 --- [nio-8100-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue]
```

**Is there a way to serialize MappingJacksonValue or do I have to make changes to the return type?**

Comment: I see that `MappingJacksonValue` is non-final. Then, it should be possible to extend the class as a new class which also implements `Serializable`, say `CustomMappingJacksonValue extends MappingJacksonValue implements Serializable`. Did you try it?

Comment: Probably you are using the default serialization for redis, this require objects to be serializable (and `MappingJacksonValue` is not). You can use https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.html instead.

Comment: @josejuan can you suggest any example code. I am unable to execute it. it saves JSON value to Redis but it has the wrong value saved. and gives error while deserializing.

Comment: @SagarNayak post a minimal reproducible example (what you cannot serialize?), that `MappingJacksonValue` is trivial.